# I can't find anything pertaining to this particular error message

Tags: r, error-handling

So I keep getting an error message in R when I try to use the bias function here's what my code looks like so far:

```
install.packages("SimDesign")
library(SimDesign)
actual_temp<-c(68.3,70,72.4,71,67,70)
predicted_temp<-c(67.9,69,71,5,70,67,69)
bias(actual_temp, predicted_temp)
```

And here's the error message I get when I run the code:

```
Error in bias(actual_temp, predicted_temp) : 
  ncol(estimate) == length(parameter) is not TRUE
```

I've tried figuring out if my syntax is off (I'm a novice so I'm never 100% sure). I then tried copy-pasting the error into the search bar and came up with nothing. If anyone has an idea of how to fix this that would be great in case it's a problem I run into again in the future.

Edit: I tried again with some different data and it worked just fine. Is there something in this specific instance you can identify that's making it not work?

Comment: `actual_temp` Has 6 elements but `predicted_temp` has 7. Is this intentional?

Comment: You have 6 values in `actual_temp` and 7 values in `predicted_temp`. They need to be the same length. Maybe `71,5` is supposed to be `71.5`?

Comment: Is your Q answered? Changing `70,5` to `71.5` results in `[1] 0.7166667`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me. Sometimes the spacing may be the reason

```
install.packages("SimDesign")
library(SimDesign)
actual_temp <- c(68.3, 70, 72.4, 71, 67, 70)
predicted_temp <- c(67.9, 69, 71.5, 70, 67, 69)
bias(actual_temp, predicted_temp)
```